# Red Black Tree Insertion And Fixing From Pseudocode Having Issues

Tags: c, debugging, tree, segmentation-fault, red-black-tree

I have pseudo code from the book "Introduction to Algorithms" by Thomas H Cormen and other for red and black trees.

The pseudo code for insertion and insert fix are located [here](http://net.pku.edu.cn/~course/cs101/2007/resource/Intro2Algorithm/book6/chap14.htm)

I am getting a seg fault at this line: `while(n->parent->color == 'r')` within the insert fix function utilizing the below test data when trying to insert "8":

Test Data:

```
i 5
i 7
i 1
i 8
i 3
```

I believe this is due to the fact the parent of n may not exist? But I am unsure how to change the code appropriately without screwing up the pseudo code completely.:

Here is my insert:

```
void insert_fix(node * n)
{
    node * y;
    if(n->parent)
    {
        while(n->parent->color == 'r')
        {
            if(n->parent == n->parent->parent->left)
            {
                y = n->parent->parent->right;
                if(y->color == 'r')
                {
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    y->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                    n = n->parent->parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(n == n->parent->right)
                    {
                        n = n->parent;
                        rotate_left(n);
                    }
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                y = n->parent->parent->left;
                if(y->color == 'r')
                {
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    y->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                    n = n->parent->parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(n == n->parent->left)
                    {
                        n = n->parent;
                        rotate_right(n);
                    }
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    root->color = 'b';
}
```

Here is my insert fix:

```
void insert_fix(node * n)
{
    node * y;
    if(n->parent)
    {
        while(n->parent->color == 'r')
        {
            if(n->parent == n->parent->parent->left)
            {
                y = n->parent->parent->right;
                if(y->color == 'r')
                {
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    y->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                    n = n->parent->parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(n == n->parent->right)
                    {
                        n = n->parent;
                        rotate_left(n);
                    }
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                }
            }
            else
            {
                y = n->parent->parent->left;
                if(y->color == 'r')
                {
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    y->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                    n = n->parent->parent;
                }
                else
                {
                    if(n == n->parent->left)
                    {
                        n = n->parent;
                        rotate_right(n);
                    }
                    n->parent->color = 'b';
                    n->parent->parent->color = 'r';
                }
            }
        }
    }
    root->color = 'b';
}
```

*To be clear, I added the extra if statement around the above while loop so that nothing would happen if the node was the root, however it did not solve my problem as I had hoped.

For good measure I wrote the rotate right and left functions somewhat differently based off of information I found on the internet and I think they're pretty well written:

```
void rotate_right(node *n)
{
    node* left = n->left;
    swap_nodes(n, left);
    n->left = left->right;
    if(left->right != NULL)
        left->right->parent = n;
    left->right = n;
    n->parent = left;
}

void rotate_left(node *n)
{
    node* right = n->right;
    swap_nodes(n, right);
    n->right = right->left;
    if(right->left != NULL)
        right->left->parent = n;
    right->left = n;
    n->parent = right;
}

void swap_nodes(node* oldNode, node* newNode)
{
    if(oldNode->parent == NULL)
        root = newNode;
    else
    {
        if(oldNode == oldNode->parent->left)
            oldNode->parent->left = newNode;
        else
            oldNode->parent->right = newNode;
    }

    if(newNode != NULL)
        newNode->parent = oldNode->parent;
}
```

Again, I feel my real code follows the pseudo code accurately but I cannot figure out the part I'm missing.

Let me know! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a bug in the RBT insert algorithm in CLRS. When the color of both parent and uncle is red, the algorithm first repaints the parent and uncle into black and then moves up by, as in your code, `n = n->parent->parent`. However, that is not the end of that case. Instead, the algorithm should recursively call itself after moving up. Namely, there should be, taking your code for example, a statement like this:

```
insert_fix(n);
```

after `n = n->parent->parent.`

Please correct me if I am wrong. BTW, [the wikipedia entry "red-black tree"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree) may be helpful in this case.